# can I add custom nested CloudFormation stack to AWS Amplify OR can I create a custom Lambda function/SQS with GraphQL/AppSync?

Tags: aws-appsync, aws-amplify, aws-serverless

Spending more than a day I doubt the answer is Yes.

Want to double check though.

Creating Lambda functions is possible with REST APIs. But I need it with GraphQL. As I understand, currently creating Lambda function from CLI for GraphQl is not supported - right ?

In my app one party places an order => mutates DynamoDB table Orders => DynamoDB triggers a Lambda function that in turn mutates DynamoDB table Offers (changes offer's status). This change should notify subscribed parties.

I could do it in a separate Lambda function or in a Lambda function that serves as a Resolver. But either way I do not see a way of doing it using AWS Amplify.

Resolver Lambda function should also be manually added in console (providing Lambda ARN). Is there a way of adding it using CLI or config files or nesting a CloudFormation stack template ?

I know I can do all manually in console. But I need to find a way using AWS Amplify so that I have a parent and nested CloudFormation stack templates.

Possible workaround I see is:

- setting up GraphQL API using AWS Amplify;
- setting up rest of the serverless environment with AWS SAM or Serverless Framework;
- have to manually connect (in console) Lambda and SQS with AppSync's DynamoDB.

Is my understanding correct? Is there a better way than this workaround ?

I am building my front end app in React. [This AWS Amplify page](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/manualsetup#carthage-setup) shows how resources such as SQS can be created for iOS. Is there anything similar for React ?

Thank you

Comment: This is being worked on in https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/pull/581